# RxJS take() operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the take() operator. In it's definition it is supposed to return the first value emitted by the observable but to me it seems like it's returning the last one.

I tried the following test to understand it better :

UsersService.ts

```
import {User} from '../models/user.model';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UsersService {

  userObs = new BehaviorSubject<{test: string}>(null);

  testEmit(inp: string) {
    this.userObs.next({test: inp});
  }
}
```

and a component.

users.component.html

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #inp>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="testTake(inp)">Emit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

users.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../models/user.model';
import {UsersService} from '../services/users.service';
import {interval, Observable, Observer, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usersService.userObs.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((data: {test: string}) => {
      console.log(data.test);
    });
  }

  testTake(inp: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.usersService.testEmit(inp.value);
  }
}
```

In the view I type something in the input and I click the button to emit it and then I go to another component and come back to this one to retrigger the OnInit() function and what I get in the console is the last value I wrote in the input.
Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very obvious as **BehaviorSubject has the characteristic that it stores the “current” value. This means that you can always directly get the last emitted value from the BehaviorSubject**.

And you are using singleton service. So when when you move to other route and come back, it gonna emit, last stored value.

**[This could help you to understand it further](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)**

If that is not what you want, I'd recommend to use `Subject` instead of `BehaviourSubject`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so when I combine ```take``` and ```BehaviorSubject``` I'm only benefiting from the fact that ```take``` does the unsubscribe on its own?

Comment: `Take` is an operator. It acts on the observable emitted value. So, `take` can't  be `unsubscribed`, any observable can be unsubscribed. So, yes in your case observable is still alive when you switch between pages/routes.

Comment: So if I switched BehaviorSubject  to Subject I should get the first value no matter how many values I emit?

Comment: No.  it doesn't mean it. It means if observable is emitting `streams of data`, in that case take operator will  take `first stream data`. If you emit value through observable one by one. It will consider all values. It has to be `streams of data`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nyks-rxjs-skelaton-mirhme?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts check it. I created for you so you can understand what I mean.

Comment: Ok so an array is considered to be a stream of data, but why isn't the array returned by the get request also considered to be a stream of data?